# Get value out of query string with regex?

Tags: regex

I want to find the value corresponding to a specific key1 in QUERY_STRING using regex.

example :

```
"page?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"

"page?key2=value2&key1=value1&key3=value3"

"page?key2=value2&key3=value3&key1=value1"
```

I've found a regex like the one below, but it doesn't work the way I want it to in this situation.

```
key1=([^&]*)

"page?kkkkkkkey1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3"

"page?key2=value2&kkkkkkey1=value1&key3=value3"

"page?key2=value2&key3=value3&kkkkkkey1=value1"
```

Comment: No, don't use regex. Use the appropriate URL parser of your language.

Comment: "*it doesn't work the way I want it to in this situation*" - what **do** you want then?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
(\&|\?)key1=([^&]*)
```

This way the regex will match only if the the **key1** is prepended by **&** or **?**

**Note**: Now the value will be the second parenthesis match